# where to place UNetbootin

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I am in the process of downloading Ubuntu. I want it in a bootable flash drive.
To do this I am told to add UNetbootin to make it Live.
My present OS is Windows 10. Which UNetbootin should I use Windows UNetbootin or Linux UNetbootin, and where do I download UNetbootin anywhere or on the flash drive itself?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Windows, you should download the windows version of UNetbootin from [here](http://unetbootin.github.io/). You do not have to put it in UNetbootin in USB but install it in your Windows.

After you've downloaded, run UNetbootin, then

1. select the "disk image" option and
2. supply it with the Ubuntu ISO file you have downloaded
3. Select your USB drive from the list and
4. click OK.

[image]